# How can I use a map in UI5 GeoMap?

Tags: api, sapui5, sap-fiori, geomap

I should use the basemap.at free online map to my SAPUI5 application. I can't achieve, to use it.

```
var oMapConfig = {
                "MapProvider": [{
                    "name": "GMAP",
                    "Source": [{
                        "id": "s1",
                        "url": 'https://maps3.wien.gv.at/basemap/bmaphidpi/normal/google3857/9/178/278.jpeg?api_key=a73befc7-575f-48cb-8eb9-b05172a8c9e3'
                    }]
                }],
```

I don't where could I find the good URL, or what should I set in.

Tried to find the API and other hints, but didn't find any solution and I don't know how could I do it. I think it's easy (basemap.at, wien.gv.at, data.gv.at) but I don't know what to do.

I tried it with Google Maps, with this URL: [https://mt.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={X}&y={Y}&z={LOD}](https://mt.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x=%7BX%7D&y=%7BY%7D&z=%7BLOD%7D)  and it works well.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://answers.sap.com/answers/13037454/view.html

Answer (score 0):

Following @BoghyonHoffmann suggestion, I believe you should use the following url:
[https://maps3.wien.gv.at/basemap/bmaphidpi/normal/google3857/{LOD}/{X}/{Y}.jpeg?api_key=a73befc7-575f-48cb-8eb9-b05172a8c9e3](https://maps3.wien.gv.at/basemap/bmaphidpi/normal/google3857/%7BLOD%7D/%7BX%7D/%7BY%7D.jpeg?api_key=a73befc7-575f-48cb-8eb9-b05172a8c9e3)

Also you could make use of all of available sources:

```
    var oMapConfig = {
            "MapProvider": [{
                "name": "GMAP",
                "Source": [{
                    "id": "s0",
                    "url": "https://maps.wien.gv.at/basemap/bmaphidpi/normal/google3857/{LOD}/{X}/{Y}.jpeg?api_key=a73befc7-575f-48cb-8eb9-b05172a8c9e3"
                },{
                    "id": "s1",
                    "url": "https://maps1.wien.gv.at/basemap/bmaphidpi/normal/google3857/{LOD}/{X}/{Y}.jpeg?api_key=a73befc7-575f-48cb-8eb9-b05172a8c9e3"
                },{
                    "id": "s2",
                    "url": "https://maps2.wien.gv.at/basemap/bmaphidpi/normal/google3857/{LOD}/{X}/{Y}.jpeg?api_key=a73befc7-575f-48cb-8eb9-b05172a8c9e3"
                },{
                    "id": "s3",
                    "url": "https://maps3.wien.gv.at/basemap/bmaphidpi/normal/google3857/{LOD}/{X}/{Y}.jpeg?api_key=a73befc7-575f-48cb-8eb9-b05172a8c9e3"
                },{
                    "id": "s4",
                    "url": "https://maps4.wien.gv.at/basemap/bmaphidpi/normal/google3857/{LOD}/{X}/{Y}.jpeg?api_key=a73befc7-575f-48cb-8eb9-b05172a8c9e3"
                }]
            }],
```